# I am getting an error in output terminal of VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am getting the following error in the VS Code output terminal:

***'C:\Users\S' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.***

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated...

Comment: What did you do to get that error?

Comment: Check your file path

Comment: You may have to wrap that part of your command in quotes.  I'm guessing that `S` is not your username but that it is `S<space>something`.

Comment: @ Mark, yes its S Gupta. I suspect it may be due to the space. However, how do i resolve this?

Comment: It would help to see your full command but generally you include your path in quotes like `ls 'myFilePath'` or `echo '${fileDirname}'`

Answer (score 1):

The user "S" doesn't exist on your computer. Please change the username settings in VSCode

Reg

Comment: User name is S Gupta. The error may be due to the space in user name. How do i resolve this.